# Spring MVC 3.2.8: Create a new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext and loading the definitions from the given XML files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an Spring MVC 3.2.8 app, and I want to run StandAlone process to generate a PDF. I want to initialize the container and manage beans from an stand-alone app.
I have this piece of code:

```
   public class CreatePDF {


        private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger   (ImportEcolabelToolboxToECAT.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) {


            String[] configLocations = new String[] {   

"C:/Development/Workspaces/EclipseWS/devices/deviceWeb/src/main/resources/com/nicinc/dao/dataAccessContext.xml",

"C:/Development/Workspaces/EclipseWS/devices/deviceWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dao/databaseMessageSource.xml",
                                                        "C:/Development/Workspaces/EclipseWS/devices/deviceWeb/src/main/resources/com/nicinc/services/impl/servicesContext.xml", 
                                                        "C:/Development/Workspaces/EclipseWS/devices/deviceWeb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml",                                              
                                                        "C:/Development/Workspaces/EclipseWS/devices/deviceWeb/src/main/resources/com/nicinc/controller/propertyeditors/propertyeditorsContext.xml"};

            FileSystemXmlApplicationContext ctx = 
                    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(configLocations, true);

        }
    }
```

But I have this error when running the app.

```
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

and here the definition from the file `dataAccessContext.xml`  :

```
 <!-- The PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer replaces placeholders in Spring bean definitions with the values from the chosen properties files. -->
    <!-- There is an example use in the datasource definition below. Look for the $\{jdbc.*} values. -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:com/nicinc/dao/jdbc-test.properties</value>                 
                <value>classpath:com/nicinc/dao/dbMessageSource.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform"   value="${hibernate.dialect}"/>
                <property name="generateDdl"        value="false"/>
                <property name="showSql"            value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>         
    </bean>   

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The javax.naming package comprises the JNDI Api. Since it is just an API its implementation you will have to provide. Generally the implementation is provided by App server. As per the error you are Missing the JNDI implementation. 
Possible solution:

1. If you dont have any javaee related requirement then you should directly use DriverManagerDataSource.
2. You need to provide your own implementation.Below link might help.
   [using application data source locally.](http://penguindreams.org/blog/running-beans-that-use-application-server-datasources-locally/)